# Prove $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

$G$ is a set.
$$G=\left\{\begin{vmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0  & 1\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}0 & 1 \\-1 & 0\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0  & -1\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1  & 0\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}i & 0 \\ 0  & i\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}0 & i \\ -i  & 0\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}-i & 0 \\ 0  & i\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}0 & -i \\ i  & 0\end{vmatrix}\right\}$$ and $(G, \times)$ is a group.

If
$$H=\left\{\begin{vmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0  & 1\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0  & -1\end{vmatrix}\right\}$$ and
$$K=\left\{\begin{vmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0  & 1\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0  & -1\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}i & 0 \\ 0  & i\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}-i & 0 \\ 0  & -i\end{vmatrix}\right\},$$
then $H$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

My questions are :

a. How do I prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$?
I knew that to prove if $H$ is a normal subgroup I have to prove that each left coset of $H$ in K is a right coset of $H$ in $K.$ But I don't know how apply that to the matrices.

b. What is every element of factor group $G/H?$

Comment: note that the elements of $H$ commute with those of $K$, so $kHk^{-1}=kk^{-1}H=eH=H$

Comment: $H$ and $K$ are cyclic; I think $G\cong C_2\times C_4$

Comment: $K$ is isomorphic to $\{1,i,i^2,i^3\}$ with $i^2=-1$, so $K$ is cyclic, so $K$ is abelian, so all subgroups of $K$ are normal

Answer (score 3):

as for $H$ in $K$ you could notice that $H$ is of index 2 in K so it is normal.

Comment: And $K$ is of index $2$ in $G$!

Answer (score 2):

**a.**  $H=\{I,-I\}$, so, for all $k\in K$, $kH=\{kI,-kI\}=\{k,-k\}$,

and also $Hk=\{Ik,-Ik\}=\{k,-k\}$,

so indeed each left coset of $H$ in $K$ is a right coset of $H$ in $K$, so $H\lhd K$.

**b.**  One element of $G/H$, for example,

is  $\left\{I\begin{bmatrix}0 & i \\ -i  & 0\end{bmatrix},   -I\begin{bmatrix}0 & i \\ -i  & 0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ =$ \left\{\begin{bmatrix}0 & i \\ -i  & 0\end{bmatrix},   \begin{bmatrix}0 & -i \\ i  & 0\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$

Now can you find the others?

Answer (score -1):

Longer method than Yotam's: conjugate each subgroup by each element of $K$ and $G$ and show that they are invariant. You'll have to do $4*2 + 8*4 = 40$ different conjugations, but this isn't so large as to make the computation unfeasible to do by hand.